# For Loop stops before condition (C)

Tags: c

I am very new to C language. I have a little problem that I can't figure out. I made a lottery program which generates 6 random numbers to each columns, and repeats according to the row value entered. The only problem I am having is the program stops after 9 succesful rows even though the input is higher.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int KURE_SIZE = 50;
    int ROWS = 0;
    int i, j, a;
    int lottery[ i ][ j ];
    int kure[ KURE_SIZE ];

    for( a = 1; a <= KURE_SIZE; ++a )
        kure[a] = a;

    printf("How many games do you want to play? (MAX.500) ");
    scanf("%d", &ROWS);
    printf("\n");


        for( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ){

            printf("Game %d :", i + 1);

            srand ( (unsigned int) time(NULL));

                for( j = 0; j < 6; j++ ){

                    int x = 1 + rand() % KURE_SIZE;
                    lottery[ i ][ j ] = kure[ x ];

                    printf("%5d", lottery[ i ][ j ]);
                    kure[x] = kure[ KURE_SIZE-- ];

                }

            printf("\n");

        }

    printf("\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

What might be the reason for this problem? I thought it may be a memory issue, but I don't know.

I'd be appreciated for some help. I love this site and the helpful community.

Comment: One issue is the loop:

`for( ia = 1; a <= KURE_SIZE; ++a )
        kure[a] = a;`

Which has an off by one error. You write to kure at index KURE_SIZE, which is out of bounds.

Edit: Also you are initializing your array: `int lottery[ i ][ j ];` with unitialized values, which will definitely cause some undefined behavior.

Comment: `int lottery[ i ][ j ];` i and j are uninitialized. In C you need to allocate memory before use it. Maybe write `int lottery[500][6]` ? But be careful you need to verify that the user don't put more than 500 in ROW.

Comment: just an aside, you should seed the random number generator only once (move your `srand` line above all your loops)

Comment: Please move `srand(...);` to the start of `main`. You should call it *once*.

Comment: Don't write variable with majuscule. In C, only MACRO should be write in full majuscule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition of a variable length array

```
int lottery[ i ][ j ];
```

is incorrect because variables `i` and `j` are not initialized.

Also this loop is invalid

```
   for( a = 1; a <= `KURE_SIZE`; ++a )
        kure[a] = a;
```

there ia an attempt to access memory beyond the array. The valid range of indices for this array is `[0, KURE_SIZE-1]`

Thus this statement

```
int x = 1 + rand() % KURE_SIZE;
```

must be changed to

```
int x = rand() % KURE_SIZE;
```

because variable `x` used as an index for the array `kure`

Comment: I changed the range but this caused problem on random numbers, tried initializing(i=0,j=0 right?) but nothing is changed. I tried everything that said but no luck. Might be the cause of this problem is the method I used to prevent dublication for 6 random values? Because when I delete that, it lasts much longer(63 rows max.) but still not high as I entered.

Comment: @thefrogking As I wrote you have to correctly define array lottery

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused by correctly defining the array

Comment: @thefrogking The loop must be define after ROWS has valid value. The number of rows and columns or a variable length array shall be known when the array is defined.